# Methods to check if an ideal of a polynomial ring is prime

Tags: polynomials, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals

Fix $\ell \geq 3$, $r \geq 2$ and $1 \leq k \leq \ell - 1$ and $z_1, \ldots, z_\ell \in \mathbb{C}$ with $z_i \neq 0$ for all $i$ and $z_i \neq z_j$ for all $i \neq j$. Now consider the (irreducible, non-homogeneous) polynomials

$q_i = z_{\ell}x_i^r - z_ix_{\ell}^r - (z_{\ell} - z_i)$ for $1 \leq i < \ell$ and

$p = z_\ell x_0^{r + k} - x_1\cdots x_k(1 - x_{\ell}^r)$

in $R = \mathbb{C}[x_0, \ldots, x_{\ell}]$. I am interested in the ideal $I = (q_1, \ldots, q_{\ell - 1}, p) \subset R$. After having computed examples using Sage/Singular, I think that $I$ is prime, but I don't see how to prove this. Does anyone know some method which could be applied to this ideal to check if it is prime?

Comment: how about the familiar theorem that an ideal is prime iff the quotient ring is an integral domain?

Comment: You could try examining the Groebner bases (with respect to various term orders) to see if you can spot some pattern.  If you can describe an explicit Groebner basis then you should have a good shot at proving that the ideal is prime.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thank you for the hint. I just checked and it turns out that the basis given above already is a Groebner basis. I know about the algorithm of Gianni-Trager-Zacharias, but I don't see how knowing a Groebner basis makes this algorithm easier. Maybe I am missing something obvious here (probably due to my lack of understanding of commutative algebra).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know this ideal is prime?

Comment: @NilsAmend : It's not necessarily a slam dunk, but what you can try to do is to step through a primality testing algorithm in slow motion and see if you can make sense of what's happening, in a way that lets you prove "in words" that the result will always be prime. (Finding a Groebner basis in the first place is often a big stumbling block in this plan, but you've already gotten over that hurdle.)

Comment: @ZachFlores : It is a long story, but basically I wanted to (locally) find the defining equations for some projective curve and therefore wanted to use the primary decomposition of some ideal. Primality of the ideal above would prove that I guessed the correct primary decomposition.

Comment: @TimothyChow : I tried this before (with the aforementioned algorithm) without knowing that my generators are a Groebner basis, but I guess knowing this makes it possible to simplify some of the computations. Maybe it would help to understand how this algorithm is actually implemented in, for example, Singular. I'll just give it another try.

Comment: The algorithm of Gianni-Trager-Zacharias seems to work here, but there is one problem in applying it that I can't solve yet. I posted this as a seperate question [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/257393/irreducibility-over-the-field-of-fractions-of-a-quotient-of-a-polynomial-ring) (because I think it is interesting on its own).